# Search for files with extensions

Tags: powershell

I need to find document (*.txt or *.doc) that have content "bla bla" in recursive mode. To do search in all files I can use command:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Get-Content | Select-String -pattern "bla bla"
```

But how to ask system search only *.txt and *.doc files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-Include` parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -Include "*.txt","*.doc" | Select-String -pattern "bla bla"
```

You can pass an array of strings to it. From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx):

> -Include < String[] >
>
> Gets only the specified items. The value of this parameter qualifies
>   the Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as "*.txt".
>   Wildcards are permitted.

Comment: You can ommit the Get-Content, Select-String can handle the pipeline input :-)